# CSS: hide element but keep width (and not height)

Tags: css, height, width, hide

- `display:none` will completely hide an element as if it now had a width and height of zero
- `visibility:hidden` on the other hand will hide an element but reserve a rectangle of the element's original width and height in the document.

Is there a way through pure CSS, to hide an element such that it takes up zero height but its original width? Setting its height to zero doesnt work because I dont know to which height to set the element to once I want to show it again.

Specifically I want to achieve the following:

```
#top ul        {take up zero height but original width}
#top:hover ul  {restore original dimensions}
```

Edit: solved! The idea is to set `height:auto` to restore the original height.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/yP59s/ for the full version or here the css:

```
ul {margin:0px}
#top {border:1px solid}
#top ul {height:0px;overflow:hidden}
#top:hover ul {height:auto;}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="top">
    <h1>foobar</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
blubber
```

Comment: Just set height: auto when you want to 'restore' the height.

Comment: I would not recommend to use "top" as an element ID, this is a reserved word.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you might want to use a **small** height (e.g., 1px or 2px) instead of 0.  Otherwise, with a height of 0, there will be no surface area over which to hover.

Comment: @AxelAmthor the actual id is not "top" - I just changed it for pasting it here

Comment: @Sildoreth the height is set for the `ul` insude the `#top` - so as long as whatever else is in `#top` doesnt get resized, it's fine

Comment: @powerbuoy yes, that was indeed what I was looking for - I added some additional comments to the answer of Axel Amthor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#top         { width: 300px; height:0px; max-height:0px; }
#top:hover   {height: auto; width: 300px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5cgY/

Comment: `height:auto` was what I was looking for, thanks! Though it has to be combined with `visibility:hidden` when not hovering and `visibility:visible` when hovering because otherwise the content is still displayed even though its height is 0px.

Comment: check the jsfiddle, giving it a overflow:hidden is enough

Answer (score 1):

using css

```
<a href="#box1">Show Box 1</a>|<a href="#box2">Show Box 2</a>|<a href="#hidebox">Hide All</a>

<div id="box1" class="box"> Contents of Box 1 </div>
<div id="box2" class="box"> Contents of Box 2 </div>
```

and css

```
.box{
border: 2px solid #ccc;
padding:20px;
margin:20px 0 0;
max-height:150px;
max-width:300px;
display:none;  }



.box:target{
    display:block;
}
```

and i found this fiddle quite a few months back, can be helpful:
http://jsfiddle.net/DbXQs/